# How to make an object explode/blast out of a launcher?

Tags: animation, physics

So basically, I have an object as a launcher and an object that resides in it.

I want the object in the launcher to blast/move out very fast, hit a wall, and crack down.

If the blasting/moving out and cracking down after collision is 2 questions in one, I'm okay with getting an answer only for the blasting out.

I'd be grateful if anyone could demonstrate how to do this, whether with just the default cube.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create the object that is supposed to break, subvidide it a bit, in *Object > Quick Effect > Cell Fracture*, choose the amount of fragments with the *Source Limit* value, click *OK*. Keep the fragments selected, parent to the original object. Create the wall.

Select the original object, animate it (throw it against the wall), at the frame where it is supposed to explode, make it disappear (you can keyframe the *Viewports* and *Renders* visibility in the *Object panel > Visibility*).

Select one fragment, give it a *Physics > Rigid Body, Type > Active, Shape > Convex Hull*. At frame 0 enable the *Animated* option and keyframe, at the frame where the object is supposed to explode, deactivate and keyframe again. Also keyframe its visibility in the *Object panel > Visibility* so that it becomes visible when the object hits the wall.

Select all the other fragments, shift select the one you've set and *Object > Rigid Body > Copy from Active*, and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>L</kbd> > *Link Animation Data* so that all the other fragments share the same physics settings and the same keyframes.

Play:

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer! However, the main question was to make an object blast out of a launcher, In a way that looks natural (for example a canon) not as though it was animated out to go forward in a straight line.

Comment: @TheUnknownContributor What does not work for you? Just to be clear, to get the momentum you need to animate the first few frames by keyframing the location. Then switch on the physics and let the simulation do the job. For Rigid body, the switch is the *Animation* setting that you can be keyframed. For cloth sim, it's the *Pin* group and for *Soft body* it's the *Goal* setting. Here is an example with the *Cloth* physics: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lvhic.gif The *Pin* vertex group is controlled by a *Vertex Weight Mix* modifier.

Comment: @ The Unknown Contributor, as Blunder says, you can animate the projectile with its Animated option that you keyframe, then let the physics act on it, the rest is exactly as I show

Comment: @Blunder Thanks for the advice!